# Xamarind Android Binding: Implementor of generic interface does not override abstract method

Tags: generics, xamarin, binding, xamarin.android

I am working on creating a binding for an Android library. The library has the following class:

```
public interface GenericProcessListener<P, M, D> {
    void onStatusChanged(P process, M model, D processDetails);
    void onCompleted(P process, M model, D processDetails);
}
```

In `metadata.xml`, I exclude both methods:

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='io.mpos.transactionprovider']/interface[@name='GenericProcessListener']/method[@name='onStatusChanged']" />
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='io.mpos.transactionprovider']/interface[@name='GenericProcessListener']/method[@name='onCompleted']" />
```

However, when compiling, I get the following error:

```
Error:  error: GenericProcessListenerImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method onCompleted(Object,Object,Object) in GenericProcessListener
```

`GenericProcessListenerImplementor` is a class generated by Xamarin. Its contents are

```
package mono.io.mpos.transactionprovider;

public class GenericProcessListenerImplementor
    extends java.lang.Object
    implements
        mono.android.IGCUserPeer,
        io.mpos.transactionprovider.GenericProcessListener
{
    /** @hide */
    public static final String __md_methods;
    static {
        __md_methods =
            "";
        mono.android.Runtime.register 
        ("IO.Mpos.Transactionprovider.IGenericProcessListenerImplementor, 
        MPOSBindings, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", 
        GenericProcessListenerImplementor.class, __md_methods);
    }


    public GenericProcessListenerImplementor ()
    {
        super ();
        if (getClass () == GenericProcessListenerImplementor.class)
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate("IO.Mpos.Transactionprovider.IGenericProcessListenerImplementor, MPOSBindings, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "", this, new java.lang.Object[] {  });
    }

    private java.util.ArrayList refList;
    public void monodroidAddReference (java.lang.Object obj)
    {
        if (refList == null)
            refList = new java.util.ArrayList ();
        refList.add (obj);
    }

    public void monodroidClearReferences ()
    {
        if (refList != null)
            refList.clear ();
    }
}
```

What to do? Unfortunately I cannot exclude the whole class as I need its subclasses.

Comment: I am not an expert here thus just a comment perhaps explore something on the line of `<remove-node path="/api/package[starts-with(@name,...` instead of two?

Comment: Do you have diagnostic build output? Bindings don't handle generics well and thus you either need to simplify parameters to `java.lang.Object`, or write your own JNI code to handle the situation.

https://gist.github.com/brendanzagaeski/9607158#file-metadata-xml-L70-L81

Comment: Even if I simplify parameters to java.lang.Object (as in the gist), I run into the same issue...

Comment: [I found this for you](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19740)

Comment: I had the same problem, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401752/2001934), worked for me.