# Xamarin Android Binding Library is not abstract

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I have created a xamarin android binding library (https://github.com/ScarlettCode/ChipDna) and I've got one error I'm trying to solve.

If I remove the node then there isn't an error but ideally I'd like to fix the main error without removing the node

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.creditcall.chipdnamobile']/interface[@name='IUnsolicitedMessageListener']" ></remove-node>
```

This is the error I get when building the binding project without the node removed.

```
IUnsolicitedMessageListenerImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method onUnsolicitedMessage(db) in IUnsolicitedMessageListener public class IUnsolicitedMessageListenerImplementor
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a abstract interface in Java file? Do you implement the methods? There is one [Binding a Java Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/) article that you can take a look.

Comment: There is a public interface IUnsolicitedMessageListener in the Java file. The java library implements the methods I think

Comment: Please check if implement this interface and implement all methods in Java file, because the error means that you don't implement the methods.

Comment: I had same issue, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401752/2001934). Worked for me.